# Post deletion by me and loss of 8 points

Tags: support, reputation

When answers have been deleted by SE, I gained points.

Twice, when I deleted my own answers because others expressed a problem with my answers, I lost 8 points each time.

I'm not concerned about the points, but curious as to the reason for such a high negative consequence for deleting my own posts as opposed to waiting for mod deletion.

I've read the Q&A on deletions, but didn't find an answer.

[How did Princess Argyro lose her breast?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/1968/how-did-princess-argyro-lose-her-breast/2995#2995)

Answer (score 4):

Any reputation change you receive from a question or answer [is reversed when that post is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/274942), unless the post was

1. At least 60 days old.
2. At a score of 3 or more.

None of your deleted posts had net scores of more than 0. Here are your three answers:

- [Is “The Secret of Roan Inish” derived from a specific myth?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/a/2974/183) This had a score of +1/-1, giving you 8 points - 10 points for an upvote and -2 for a downvote. When a moderator deleted this on September 26, you lost those 8 points.
- [How does the Devil come to be horned?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/a/2993/183) This had a score of +0/-2, giving you -4 points. This was reversed when you deleted it two days ago, so you gained back those 4 points.
- [How did Princess Argyro lose her breast?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/a/2995/183) As with your first answer, this had a score of +1/-1, so you gained 8 points, and then lost them when you deleted your answer.

Reputation changes from deletion don't depend on who deletes the answer. And it isn't punishment - it's simply the lack of the reward you received when your answers were upvoted.

Comment: Ah. I didn't see any points on Princess Argyro when it was deleted and didn't recall a +1 ever having been given, so was confused.  In the future, I'll trust the 'points wizard'. Thank you for your time to research and explain. It was very helpful, and I did think it mattered who deleted.

Answer (score 1):

It's the way Stack Exchange works. You delete a post, all net reputation from it is cancelled. So if one deletes a question with 5 upvotes and 2 downvotes, he loses 22 rep.

Comment: 5uv = 50.   2dv= -4.   Wouldn't +46 be lost and -4 gained on deletion, so total loss is the 50 points?  If I'm now seeing this correctly, you don't "lose" exactly - you end up where you started before writing the post that got deleted. A 'null and void' process. Or am I still in the dark?

Comment: Questions give 5 per upvote.

Comment: Ok, found the Help area on Qs. Haven't asked a Q yet (too busy bleeding over answers <s>). Thanks, I see where your answer came from now.